# How keep track of a walk in a google map in kotlin

Tags: google-maps, kotlin

I' m trying to keep track of a walk using google maps API in kotlin.

For now I get only the last known current location ( which actually is not the real current one)

This is mine MapsActivity code:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.example.macc_project.R
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_google)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)



    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap

        map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)

        setUpMap()
    }



    private fun setUpMap() {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }

        // 1
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        // 2
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            // 3
            if (location != null) {
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
            }
        }


    }
}
```

How can I keep track of the entire walk that I do? For example painting a blue line that follows my walk, from an initial state to a final one

Comment: Do you want it to keep tracking the movement even if the user navigates away from the app or turns off the screen?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes I want this behaviour

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can exploit Google Api Client and LocationListener as in this  link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938924/how-to-draw-a-real-time-route-in-android-using-google-maps-v2-and-gps/43287589

Comment: I made an app that tracked location about 8 years ago so my knowledge is very out of date. I was just going to suggest the general strategy. You need a foreground service to monitor the position so you don't miss location points when the activity is not on screen. I haven't worked with services in a long time, so I don't know the recommended way to get services to communicate with Activities.

Comment: But I think in this case since you don't need the service to run when the Activity is finished, you could use an AndroidViewModel implementation to start the service and end it in `onCleared()`. The Service could add location points to a `MutableLiveData<List<MyLocationWrapper>>` that the Activity observes.

Comment: That only covers the need to continually track location. I don't know about drawing the points on the map with lines connecting them, since I haven't used the API in so many years.